# Android MediaRecorder and FileDescriptor

Tags: android, streaming, file-descriptor, mediarecorder

I am developing an app that will allow users to cast the screen of an android phone directly to another phone. It is based on libstreaming library with a few modifications.

I have setup MediaRecorder, but the output is not sent to a file but to a file descriptor. I have two file descriptors created with ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
...
FileDescriptor fd = mParcelWrite.getFileDescriptor();
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fd);
... here I continue with prepare, start, etc.
```

Then the output is read in the second file descriptor. The stream is processed so the headers that don't exist yet in the mp4 file can be skipped but the video can be streamed.

```
InputStream is = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(mParcelRead);
try {
  byte buffer[] = new byte[4];
  // Skip all atoms preceding mdat atom
  while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    while (is.read() != 'm') ;
    is.read(buffer, 0, 3);
    if (buffer[0] == 'd' && buffer[1] == 'a' && buffer[2] == 't') break;
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't skip mp4 header :/");
  stop();
  throw e;
}
(After this point the stream is sent over the network)
```

The thing is that apparently after API 23, android doesn't allow non seekable file descriptors.
Any idea of how can I overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: "android doesn't allow non seekable file descriptors" -- what do you mean by "android" in that phrase? Do you mean that `MediaRecorder` does not allow non-seekable file descriptors?

Comment: This is a reply from another post: Since Android API level = 23 it is no longer possible to use non seekable file descriptors (so also ParcelFileDescriptor) when encoding MPEG4 video. As can be seen in this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/2aa74dc097fe860abc84769abf2b6e0962718471%5E%21/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp) MPEG4Writer has been modified to print error and exit when it detects file descriptor that is not seekable.

Comment: Perhaps choose a different video codec than MP4, to avoid `MPEG4Writer`.

Comment: I need it to be mp4, as the whole library relies on that format. It parses the file and generates some configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any further suggestions for you. Your existing approach is already risky IMHO. `MediaRecorder` has always wanted seekable streams for MP4; now Google is just enforcing it.

Comment: Would it be an option to lower the SDK to level 22? It should be working with that versión of the SDK. If that is the case, would it work on phones with nougat for example?

Comment: First, changing the `compileSdkVersion` never has impact on functionality. All that does is control what symbols (classes, methods, etc.) are available to you. Second, the `MPEG4Writer` that you cited is part of Stagefright, not part of your app, or even part of the `framework.jar`, and so you have no means of replacing it.